# QuickBooks Oauth 2.0 returning Invalid Request Error while getting accesstoken

Tags: oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online

I am trying to Authorize the quick-books using Oath 2.0. I have done with authorization and now trying to get access token. But while making POST request to get access token I am getting "Invalid Request Error".

```
`$adminUrl="https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer";
$client_id='Q0ble08jhv8hvQwLbBo******************';
$client_secret='ewHQsRokdOhOjcNHpt7wH***********';
$redirect_url='http://localhost/quickbooks/testaccesstoken.php';
//According to Quickbooks API need to pass Authorization Header//
 $authorizationToken=base64_encode($client_id."".$client_secret);
//Curl Post Request//
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("code" =>$code,"redirect_uri"=>$redirect_url,"grant_type"=>"authorization_code");
$headers = array();
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT__TIMEOUT, "30");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:Basic' .$authorizationToken,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept: application/json'));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

{"error":"invalid_request"}

Comment: Have you considered just using a library for this, vs. writing your own? Libraries are available - e.g. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: I have written my own according to QB documentation.

Comment: @claudio Any update?